# Manipulating Cloud Deployment Manager References

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-deployment-manager

```
$(ref.uptimecheck-example_com.name)
```

Above is a reference coming from an uptimecheck resource (`gcp-types/monitoring-v3:projects.uptimeCheckConfigs`) whose value is something like `projects/[PROJECT_ID]/uptimeCheckConfigs/[UPTIME_CHECK_ID]`

But I just need the UPTIME_CHECK_ID. I can not see any property in the documentation to simply just return that.

I tried manipulating via Jinja but it just won't work. Turns out that `$(ref)` gets compiled on the GCP API tier. So `.split('/')` will not take any effect at all. I'm not sure how to move on...

What I think of right now is maybe there is a syntax along the reference can manipulate the value?